# why does it suffice to check the conditions of probability measure on the generating set of the sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a sigma algebra $\mathcal S$ over some set $X$ which is generated by some set $S\subset \mathcal P(X)$, and a probability function $P:\mathcal S\to \mathbb R$ why is it sufficient to check the conditions: $P(A)\ge 0,P(X)=1,P(\cup_n A_n)=\sum_n P(A_n)$ for all $A,A_n\in S$ where $(A_n)$ is a disjoint sequence, to determine that $P$ is a valid probability? Intuitively it is obvious that if we check the conditions to be true on a generating set then we should have the conditions true for all the elements of $\mathcal S$, but how do we rigorously prove this fact?

For example suppose $X=\mathbb R,\mathcal S=\mathcal B$ (the Borel sigma algebra) and $S=\{I:I \mbox{ is an interval in } \mathbb R\}$. Now it is easy to check that $P(I)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{I_x}e^{-x^2/2}dx$ satisfies the requisite conditions. How does it follow that the conditions are now met for $P$? Is it because of the result known as the Carathéodory's extension theorem? If so, can anyone refer me to proof, preferably in the context of probability measure?

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, you can just use $P(A) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{A}e^{-x^2/2}dx$ for $A \in B(\mathbb{R})$.

Maybe you are interested in general situations when a "measure" defined on a smaller class $S$ of sets can be extended to a measure on the sigma algebra generated by $S$. For that, see Caratheodory's theorem. Proofs are given in Klenke's probability theory book and Folland's real analysis book.

Comment: In the example, if  I define P for all Borel sets how would I go about checking $\sigma$-additivity?

Comment: In general, if $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a measure space, and $f : X \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable, then $\nu(A) = \int_{A}f\,d\mu$ defines a measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal{F}$. The notation is $d\nu = f\,d\mu$. Use monotone convergence theorem to prove $\sigma$-additivity.